# How can I find out rsyslog server is running with errors?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

Is there any configuration in rsyslog that allows to run some script when rsyslog server is running with errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To configure rsyslog to log its own log messages add  rules like below to the syslog config file `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
syslog.*                      /var/log/rsyslog.log  # log all syslog messages
syslog.err,syslog.warn        ^/usr/local/bin/omg.sh  # run a script
```

Validate the configuration of rsyslog with this command

```
 ${PATH_TO_rsyslogd}/rsyslogd -f ${pathToConfigFile} -N1
```